# Possible to have awk exit a bash script with `exit 2`?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Depending on some conditions inside an awk script, I need to get the exit code from the awk script the pass it to the bash script, so it can exit with e.g. `exit 2`.

If I call `system("exit 2")` from awk, then the bash script still exits with `0`.

**Question**

Any ideas how I can get the value of `$code` from awk to the bash script?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# ...

awk '{
  # ...
  code=2
  # ...
}' /proc/loadavg

exit $code
```

Comment: Use `exit 2` in the `awk` script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example shell script:

```
awk -v code="2" 'BEGIN{exit code}'
shell_code=$?
echo $shell_code #just for seeing the code
exit $shell_code
```

The above shell script will exit 2, the value in awk's variable `code`

The awk one-liner could be with input file too, E.g.:

```
awk 'BEGIN{code=2} {if (something happens) exit code}' file
```

However I think you can let awk output some value instead of `exiting` a value. Then assign this awk output to shell variable. You can in your shell script decide if you want to exit the shell script with which value, up to the awk output.

Comment: Just to be clear, the exit statement does more than just exit. _The **`exit`** statement shall invoke all **`END`** actions in the order in which they occur in the program source and then terminate the program without reading further input. An exit statement inside an `END` action shall terminate the program without further execution of `END` actions. **If an expression is specified in an `exit` statement, its numeric value shall be the exit status of awk, unless subsequent errors are encountered or a subsequent exit statement with an expression is executed.**_

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{
       # ...
       # default value of code will be 0, no need to declare...
       # if something went wrong set
       code=2
       # if you need to terminate, uncomment next line
       # exit
       # otherwise processing will continue
       # ensure you don't overwrite code
     }
 END {exit code}
' /proc/loadavg
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

exit $(awk 'END{code=2; exit code}' file)
$ bash foo.sh
$ echo $?
2
```